# Using "$path" on view in aws Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, presto, amazon-athena

i have a table which has a complex type field inside (kind of json).
i created a view on that table to unnest the complex type to table.

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test AS
SELECT
, "t1"."first"
, "inner"."inner_first"
, "$path"
FROM
t t1
, UNNEST("inners") t (inner)
LIMIT 10

i use the $path function to query my data based on the file name.

unfortunately, when i tried query $path on the view it doesnt work, simply returned nothing.
So i decided to add to my view the $path field in order to query it outside (as you can see above).

but it still dosent work, when i query:
select * from test
where "$path" = 'x'

i dont get the relevant result.
it seems like something inside the s3 path is making problems.

when i try: where "$path" like '%s3://bucket/output/table/part-00000-01131f4f-3fba-4711-8372-11df66a4224a-c000.snappy.parquet%' -> it still not working.
when i try:

1. where "$path" like '%c000.snappy.parquet%'
   or
2. where "$path" like '%part-00000-%'
   it suddenly works on very small set of characters.

but i cannot understand the logic, i thought about hidden character but in the bottom line it just a regular s3 path, for example:
s3://bucket/output/table/part-00000-01131f4f-3fba-4711-8372-11df66a4224a-c000.snappy.parquet

please let me know if you faced that weird case.

thanks!

Comment: Can you update exactly the query that you are trying to run with $path?  in your query you mentioned s3 twice '%s3://bucket/s3://bucket/output/table/part-00000-01131f4f-3fba-4711-8372-11df66a4224a-c000.snappy.parquet%' which definitely will not work

Comment: yea yea its a mistake of course , the path is '%s3://bucket/output/table/part-00000-01131f4f-3fba-4711-8372-11df66a4224a-c000.snappy.parquet%'. i edited the question - thanks!


as for the query, im trying:
select * from test where $path='s3://bucket/output/table/part-00000-01131f4f-3fba-4711-8372-11df66a4224a-c000.snappy.parquet'

i dont get anything back. tried also like '%part-00000-01131f4f-3fba-4711-8372-11df66a4224a-c000.snappy.parquet%'...still not working :(

Comment: Can you tell me why do you want to compare it with the full file name? It will not only scan this file but it will scan all files then filter the result. I just tried a query SELECT "$path" FROM "testtt"."test0101010" where "$path" like '%s3://test0101010/part-00079-tid-730451297822678341-1dda7027-2071-4d73-a0e2-7fb6a91e1d1f-0-c000.json%' and it gave me result fine.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your responses!!

As for the purpose, im trying to create a process that get files paths from Kinesis, query the inner complex field (using that "test" that has Unnest function in it) of the file and insert it to Aurora DB using Lambda function. I need to query by the path in order to get the specific data.

Do you familiar with that kind of process, maybe a better way to query a parquet file and doing unnest on complex types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give "$path" an alias to be able to query the column, or use the default _col4. For example:

```
create view myview as select "$path" as path from...
```

then

```
select path from myview
```